# MultiThreaded Libcurl

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

I need to execute parallel HTTP requests using Libcurl.

From what I understand I need to create a new handle for each thread
and use `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` with some kind of Thread Local Storage.
Does the multi interface makes this task a little easier?

I'm also using cookies, does using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` will make
Libcurl load the cookie file for each thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you probably know, libcurl is not thread safe, so you should ensure that the libcurl handle is never shared between multiple threads. Each thread will need to store local data (among other things, the connection handle).

From this, it ensues that for each handle, i.e., for each thread, libcurl will need to read the cookie file from scratch, since this information cannot be shared. This is not a problem, in my opinion, although there could be issues when updating it (you will have multiple thread attempting it).

About the multi interface, it allows you to multiplex multiple transfers, so it is another approach to what you are trying to do but in a single thread.

**UPDATE March 2013**

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is now thread-safe.

> libcurl is free, thread-safe, IPv6 compatible, feature rich, well supported, fast, thoroughly documented and is already used by many known, big and successful companies and numerous applications."

Comment: libcurl is thread safe, except the global init and global cleanup. Keep this in mind!

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer, but why do you need multithreading for parallel HTTP requests?

The multi interface is designed for this purpose: you add multiple handles and then process all of them with one call, all in the same thread. From the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html):

> Enable multiple simultaneous transfers in the same thread without
>   making it complicated for the application.

If you want multiple threads, I suggest you use the easy interface in each thread, and forget about the multi interface.

Sharing simply shares data between easy handles, you can use the interface with/without the multi interface. If you do use multiple threads, you have to provide your own locking.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [**libcurl share interface**](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-share.html). It was designed for this purpose, i.e. to share data between requests:

> You can have multiple easy handles share data between them. Have them
>   update and use ***the same cookie database***, DNS cache, TLS session cache!
>   This way, each single transfer will take advantage from data updates
>   made by the other transfer(s). The sharing interface, however, does
>   not share active or persistent connections between different easy
>   handles.